# Show Div in another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a navigation cshtml view and a index view.  The nav view is on the left hand side, and when I click an item on that view I want to display a partial view inside a div in the Index view.

Here is what I am trying when a user selects a item in the Nav View

```
$.get('Home/ItemResult/', { id: item.value}, function (data) {
            $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
        });
    }
```

In my index I have this (I commented out the Html.Action (I was using that, but        need to pass a parameter from the nav view))

```
               <table class="tg">
                    <tr>
                       <th class="tg-031e">
                         <div id="partialPlaceHolder" style="display:none;">                                    
                         </div>
                          @*@Html.Action("ItemResult", "Home")*@
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                </table>
```

my layout refernces the nav view.

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            @Html.Partial("_Navigation")

            <!-- Page wraper -->
            <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

                <!-- Top Navbar -->
                @Html.Partial("_TopNavbar")

                <!-- Main view  -->
                @RenderBody()

                <!-- Footer -->
                @Html.Partial("_Footer")

            </div>
            <!-- End page wrapper-->

        </div>
```

It is hitting the controller action, but the view is not showing in the placeholder div.  Is this possible?  If so, What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The style of the div is `display:none`, which means you wouldn't see it. Is the AJAX working? Check the connection & results in your network inspector in your browser's development tools.

Comment: Yep, display none was the issue. Can you reply with a answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style of the **partialPlaceHolder** contains `display:none;` which means you won't see the result.

Remove the offending code.